# Replace placeholder in file with gradle

Tags: gradle

I have gradle task `swagger-codegen` with the following configuration:

```
swaggerSources {
  testProject {
    inputFile = file("$buildDir/generated/input.json")
    code {
      language = 'csharp'
      configFile = file('swaggergen-config.json')
    }
  }
}
```

The file `swaggergen-config.json` contains:

```json
{
  "packageName": "Package.Test",
  "packageVersion" : {version},
  "netCoreProjectFile": true
}
```

How to properly replace `{version}` placeholder with `project.version`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The swagger generator plugin looks for a file which makes this a little bit more complicated than just parsing the string and replacing the token.

A solution could be to treat the configuration file as a generated input to the `generateSwaggerCode` task. This can be done via a copy task that copies your `swaggergen-config.json` "template" and replaces the `{version}` with token `rootProject.version` using an ant `ReplaceTokens` filter during copy. Note: You'll want to switch `{version}` to the ant-style token format (e.g. `@version@`), though.

The `swaggerSources.code.configFile` closure could then be set to use the newly generated configuration.

This would be added to your `build.gradle`:

```
task generateSwaggerGenConfig(type: Copy) {
    from swaggergen-config.json
    into $buildDir/generated/swaggergen-config.json
    filter(org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens, tokens:['version:rootProject.version])
}

generateSwaggerCode.dependsOn generateSwaggerGenConfig

swaggerSources {
  testProject {
    inputFile = file("$buildDir/generated/input.json")
    code {
      language = 'csharp'
      configFile = file("$buildDir/generated/swaggergen-config.json")
    }
  }
}
```

The generated `swaggergen-config.json` would look like this

```
{
  "packageName": "Package.Test",
  "packageVersion" : @version@,
  "netCoreProjectFile": true
}
```